# Build and run a jar inside of a Gradle task

Tags: jar, gradle

I am using Java, Spring, and Gradle. I am new to gradle and am trying to understand some stuff. I currently have gradle successfully building a jar file. 
I would like to add a task so that gradle runs the jar that it builds.
this way I could do

```
./gradlew clean build run
```

or I could just do it in one command if possible. The pseudocode of which would be

```
task run {
   clean
   build
   java -jar myJar.jar
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

---INFO----

my current build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M6")
    }

}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M6")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to think in task dependencies. `run` wouldn't execute some other tasks sequentially (tasks can't do that); rather, it would declare task dependencies on its *prerequisites*, such as perhaps `jar`. Anyway, the easiest solution is to just apply the `application` plugin, which you can learn more about in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).