# Gradle task to run Nashorn JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, gradle, nashorn, avatarjs

Can there be gradle/groovy code analog for launch of `java -Djava.library.path=lib -jar lib/avatar-js.jar helloWorld.js`, that is lanching .js file with Java 8 and passing some libs

or using defined dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.oracle:avatar-js:0.10.25-SNAPSHOT"
    compile "com.oracle:libavatar-js-win-x64:0.10.25-SNAPSHOT"
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'lib'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src '
        }
    }
}
```

The only related docs I found ([Build and run a jar inside of a Gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211686/build-and-run-a-jar-inside-of-a-gradle-task)) is line from [Chapter 45. The Application Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#application_plugin)

```
 startScripts   jar     CreateStartScripts  Creates OS specific scripts to run the project as a JVM application.
```

Application plugins is Java dependent, no way to define task for JavaScript or C/C++
[CreateStartScripts](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.application.CreateStartScripts.html) requires `String mainClassName` (not file to run)

Sources at https://github.com/PaulVI/NashornSandbox

Comment: As far as I understood the question there's a possibility to start such command with `gradle` but only with invoking system command (starting external process). Have a look here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy. If that's what You're looking for and You just need to write a task that will do it let me know. Will try to help You.

Comment: Any solution for now; what I have now is https://github.com/PaulVI/NashornSandbox/issues/1

Comment: If it works it seems to be ok.

Comment: It does not. Let's continue chat on GitHub..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You have 2 gradle tasks that will run the server:

```
task runHelloWorld(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'java', '-Djava.library.path=lib', '-jar', 'lib/avatar-js.jar', 'helloWorld.js'
}

task runHelloWorld2(type: JavaExec) {
    args 'helloWorld.js'
    main 'com.oracle.avatar.js.Server'
    systemProperties 'java.library.path':'lib'
    classpath 'lib/avatar-js.jar'
}
```

Comment: This works, however without output to console. Spent an hour until checked it is actually running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/calculate?amount=100&percentage=7

Comment: For both tasks I see std out. If it doesn't work You can set the stream with `standardOutput System.out`. Not checked but should work fine. Docs: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: Well, that seems to be combination of Java, Gradle versions. Now it is OK (Java 8; Gradle 1.11)

Comment: Maybe. Have exactly same environment (8 and 1.11).